# Using Aurora Serverless as a Replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Can Aurora Serverless or any other serverless DB be used as a replica for a mysql  instance (or any other rdbms) on an ec2? If yes,how will replication happen if the replication instance is cold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for Aurora Serverless Read Replica is in preview for Aurora Serverless v2.
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/

Answer (score 0):

I asked the support team at AWS, and they replied that as of now, it is not possible to use replication with binlog with Aurora Serverless.

You need a "provisioned" Aurora instead, in order to be able to do replication.

Now, you can still make it work with Serverless via another mechanism, which is called "AWS Database Migration Service" (AWS DMS).

With this, you can set up a replication server, and endpoint target and source that will allow you to retrieve the data from one server, and send it to another.